# Python, strings, unicode characters

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, character

`comp/INFO_MAP_ECE/101102.1.119`

This string is the output of a CPU but there are always special/non-printable characters after the number and my aim is to obtain the number excluding the text before it and special/non-printable after it. I am trying the split method but am not sure what to use for special/non-printable characters. Can anyone please suggest something? It would be a great help. thanks.

Comment: I suggest you show us the code that you use to extract the text

Comment: If one of the answers you got solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your output always looks something like what you showed, you can use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
numPattern = r'/([\d.]+)'
output = 'comp/INFO_MAP_ECE/101102.1.119'

m = re.search(numPattern, output)

if m: #If a match was found
  numString = m.group(1)  #Extracts the first group surrounded by ()
  #etc
```

The pattern here looks for a /, then some numbers and periods, then anything, and extracts just the numbers and periods.  This should work as long as you're always getting a string that matches that description.

HTH!

Comment: As I know `.` doesn't have to be escaped in a character class. So, instead of `[\d\.]+'`, the pattern should be `[\d.]+'`.

Comment: Also, I don't understand, what `.*` is doing at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Changed.  I didn't know about `.`s in character classes, so that's good to know.  I'm not entirely sure what the `.*` was doing there either.  Maybe I was thinking about the non-printable characters?

Answer (score 1):

Is the number always the same length? If so you could just slice the string.

```
'comp/INFO_MAP_ECE/101102.1.119'[18:30]
```

Comment: Not a good idea. Even if the number is the same length now, it may not always be. Also becomes pretty onerous to maintain. This is precisely what regexes were made for.